Community-a-thon 2024 kicks off on October 18th
TL;DR:

Our fifth Community-a-thon will kick off on October 18, 2024 and continue until October 23, 2024.
This is an annual event where staff at Stack Overflow are encouraged to participate on the Stack Exchange network.
The scale of the event is consistent with last year’s Community-a-thon.

What is Community-a-thon?
This is an event we hold for the staff at Stack Overflow. During the course of the event, employees are encouraged to participate on sites in the Stack Exchange network, in order to increase their familiarity with the public sites and experience things from the perspective of a community member. This is the fifth year we've held the event, and you can see our previous posts, like this one from 2023, as well as the ones from other past Community-a-thons.
The goals for the event are:

Improve empathy between all Stack Overflow employees and our sites and communities.
Achieve a high degree of participation during the event, that can hopefully carry on afterwards as well.
Increase our collective familiarity with our core product and elicit useful feedback on actionable ways to improve our functionality and user experience.

Similar to previous Community-a-thons, the event will include a competition in which participants can receive points based on engagement and activities done on network sites during the contest.
We will not have a dedicated chat room for the event, but we are letting Stackers (what we call Stack Overflow employees) who are less familiar with the Stack Exchange network know about chat, so don't be surprised if you see some newer Stackers in the Tavern or in some of the site-specific chat rooms.
Some Stackers may be participating with their staff accounts, while others may be using brand-new accounts. We're encouraging staff to create new accounts or use accounts with low rep on sites so they can better understand the new user experience. Those participating, regardless of whether they are using newer or established accounts, are encouraged to submit their feedback, observations, and experiences over the course of the event.
The scale this year
Like last year, Community-a-thon is primarily being driven by the Community Management and People Operations teams, and will run for several days (October 18-23rd), rather than weeks as we have done in the past. We want to allow Stackers across all areas of the company to gain insight into the new user experience without pulling them away from their day-to-day work of supporting and strengthening the platform.
Community is the core of Stack Exchange, and this event is an opportunity for staff who aren’t as involved on the network to become familiar with them and the community. It’s also an opportunity for staff who are regularly engaged on the network to see things through the lens of a community member.
We’re giving you this heads up because the community has given us great feedback over the years around staff participation during the event. Similar to last year, we will have an internal info session for staff, and community managers will be around to help newer members out if they have questions. We also plan to post a recap here a few weeks after the event, as we did last year.
If you have any questions related to the event or its goals, feel free to ask in an answer below.

"Stack Overflow employees" or Stack Exchange employees?

@Joachim The company that operates the Stack Exchange network generally refers to itself as "Stack Overflow".  See, e.g., financial reports from its parent company (referring to the company only as "Stack Overflow") or the terms of service (referring to "Stack Exchange, Inc. ('Stack Overflow', 'we' or 'us')").


We're encouraging staff to create new accounts or use accounts with low rep on sites so they can better understand the new user experience

Ask a few of these testers to download the entire SE data dump (entire = for all sites) so that they can assess the new SE data dump experience, and let's hear their feedback.

*without using any internal tools.

While this is worth doing, it's not really related to Community-a-thon; most employees would have no use for the data dump, or even any idea of what to do with it. That wouldn't yield any useful feedback on improving the process for users who do actually use the data dump.

@V2Blast they could provide useful feedback on improving the process for users who do actually use the data dump, as they'll experience the download part of it.

@TylerH or paid tools.

@V2Blast There is "a competition in which participants can receive points based on engagement and activities done". Seems quite simple to give people the motivation to eat that particular bit of dog food.

@FranckDernoncourt paid tools are fine, just not anything that non-employees don't have access to. Although any tool that's used should be listed in any feedback.

@TylerH well, there's a community maintained "mirror" on Archive.org which makes it easy, or Zoe's repo; we probably want to see how they feel about the new process. Although, I agree with V2Blast; this is not best use of their time. Everyone in their right mind knows the new process sucks.


elicit useful feedback on actionable ways to improve our functionality and user experience

I'd also encourage participating staff who encounter functionality or usability issues to search on MSO and/or MSE. Ex. is:q [bug] [feature-request] -[status-completed] .... I'm 10% joking here and 90% being genuine that I think finding out that the thing bothering you or that you want to change has already been brought up several years ago- maybe multiple times- is an (unhappily) integral part of the user experience here (though not necessarily unique to SO/SE). I think the value in that is in learning our perspective that many basic things we want are stuck in backlog hell or whatever name it has if it can't be called a backlog (of course, Community Asks sprints are helping, and I greatly appreciate them).

Or, if using new accounts, post the bug here themselves if they can't find it, to see what the experience reporting bugs is like.

To be honest, somehow the fact that bugs and requests sit idle for years stopped bothering me, I just learned to accept it as part of the place.

@ShadowWizard I feel the same - otherwise, since 6-8 years I've been adding various // TODO: comments to source code I've been working on (work-related and private). I do not have the courage to run git blame anymore, so it's not really SE's fault :)

@ShadowWizard and some bugs and requests are even deleted by rooma.

And if there's no post, post feedback on meta, and follow up :D

I'd note that the post is broadly similar to last year's. In my role as a Pets moderator — I noticed some activity from staff during the event, but very little to none between the previous and up-coming community-a-thon.

Achieve a high degree of participation during the event, that can hopefully carry on afterwards as well.

With this as a goal — what's being done differently to enable/encourage/activate folks to stick around after the event?

One thing that is important to note is that many Stack employees who do use the sites (both during community-a-thon or just in the course of their daily lives), do so with a separate account that is not marked as staff, either for privacy reasons, to establish some separation between work and hobbies (depending on what sites we are talking about), or for other reasons. So their participation throughout the year may not necessarily be something that would be obvious.

That said, we do hope to encourage more Stackers to take up this practice and continue their participation after the competition has concluded. I don’t have a concrete plan for that to share at this point, but after the event is over we will be evaluating how it went and next steps for encouraging continued activity going forward.

@Sasha: I do think the "encouraging folks to keep participating in the community outside of Community-a-thon" is a key aspect, and something that would have a bigger/more long-term impact than just Community-a-thon by itself. Community-a-thon is great, but finding ways to get staff to participate on the network year-round might be even better.

Depends on the impact you want to have - If we don't know someone is a SE employee, we can have empathy towards them as a person, but I don't feel it does much for empathy and communications with employees as a person. From my perspective - I feel the visibility can be important.

Something with the Community-a-thon event has been bothering me since it began, and I could never put my finger on what, exactly.
I still can't, but trying this time to at least share it, and perhaps reach some enlightenment while writing, or with help of others.
You see, in its core it's a good thing. Good intentions, good people, good outcome.
After reading now what Dan Mašek wrote here:

what is it that's so fundamentally broken in the company that you have to organize a competition with prizes to get your own employees to actually use your flag product?

I gave it more thought, about my own past and present thoughts, and it's still not that. I don't expect all the company employees to use Stack Exchange sites, it's not a shirt or a mobile device. I do expect those who should engage the community to use the sites, or at least be active, and there there is a big failure, however that's a topic for different discussion.
So, Shadow, what's going on? Perhaps adding something Journeyman Geek wrote here:

some activity from staff during the event, but very little to none between the previous and up-coming community-a-thon

Bingo! The employees who take part don't do it because they really want to, or intended to do that by themselves. They do it as part of their job.
This is not bad. The outcome is still good. But that's what bothering me, and wanted to share and remove it from my shoulders.

I wonder if this counts as the meta post you were talking about writing on the tavern :D

You know... I kinda remember some ancient ones that were kinda enjoying the site without really being forced too, despite it still being part of their jobs. I seem to remember some names... Catya, Shog9...... Wonder what happened to them.

@JourneymanGeek lol... nope. The plans for that one kind of shattered with the recent company actions.

@SPA of course. Anyone from the inside who wanders too far outside is being shut off. Naturally, the others won't even bother and we can't blame them. (We can, though, blame the company and management and that's what I do)

@ShadowWizard That is kinda the issue when AI controls the door. Just ask Hal9000. "I'm sorry Shadow, I'm afraid I can't do that"

While it’s true that this event takes place as a part of stacker’s work days, no one is forced to participate. While managers encourage their teams to sign up, it is not mandatory.
Every stack employee that takes part in the event does so because they have a desire to learn more about the sites, the network, the communities, and the user experience - or because they just enjoy using SE sites and want to get some credit for doing so on the job.

Also, as I noted here you might notice a staff member's participation on the network if they are using a personal, non-staff account.

@Sasha thanks for the response. But do note I didn't write you (the employees) are forced to take part, and I didn't intend that either. You're encouraged to take part, and that's enough. The proof is that very few to none employees do  that in other times, be it during work hours or outside of them. And again, this post isn't in order to bash the company, just explain what I think and finally realized it myself.

While it'd be great if all employees loved the company' products, in reality it's simply not feasible to expect that from every employee. Even those who do like the sites and believe in the mission, they have jobs, lives and other hobbies. How much activity would be a correct amount? Do we really need them to prove their loyalty? Having a fun little participation event with some prizes doesn't need to be analysed or thought about in the context of whether the employees are "truly" participating or just doing it because it's their job.

What fascinates me is the following snippets:

"an annual event where staff at Stack Overflow are encouraged to participate on the Stack Exchange network"
"Increase our collective familiarity with our core product"
"event will include a competition"

Honestly, what is it that's so fundamentally broken in the company that you have to organize a competition with prizes to get your own employees to actually use your flag product? (It's hardly the only mind-boggling aspect of your operations, but definitely one of the more prominent ones.)
Back when I worked on a system used on a roughly similar scale used by general public, we "ate our dogfood" all the time -- our product was the primary means of communication across the entire company, everyone used it every day. Obviously, yours is a less universal tool, but still, how (or why) did you manage to not make it a crucial part of how you operate? You even try to sell the system to others to use internally, yet you don't? What's up with that, and how do you explain that to your potential customers? Why do people even work there, if they don't give a hoot about your flag product?

it's... common for employees to not actively use the "thing" produced by the company they work for.

@KevinB Really? I guess my experience is the weird one, and I'm curious to hear the other perspectives. I mean, it depends on what you make... right now, I don't own an OSB mill, so I don't generally run my software all the time, but that's a bit different from what we're talking about here. | After 15 years you'd think they'd have this one nailed by now.

like... think about all the accountants, marketing people, business execs etc that work for SO. yea, there's stacks that are somewhat relevant to all those things... but... most normal people don't use those either.

@KevinB Sure, perhaps not many of the external ones (although people do have hobbies) -- but surely there must be some internal uses, like what the SO for Teams is meant for (I suppose?). From what I read there, it seems like they don't even have that, otherwise, why would they not be familiar with it?

@KevinB "most normal people" -- hmm, I guess therein lies my problem :D (And the place I worked at was by no means normal either, at least back then)

I certainly don't expect all Stack employees to be power users or even regular users of Stack Exchange sites. However, I do think it is reasonable to expect all Stack employees, at least who work on the Q&A product in anyway (the frontend, backend, CMs, product teams and all leadership of those teams or higher) to have a better understanding of how the sites and communities work than someone who's been a member of a given site for a few weeks or months. Currently that's... not the case.

@TylerH I agree with your expectations, although it seems to me there are opportunities to engage even non-developer internally. Given that this is the 5th year, it was rather staggering to see the findings from last year (I'd say massive ignorance). Maybe now the outcome will be better, but I'm a bit jaded by now. Still, 5 years and nothing much seems to be changing. Seems the priorities are elsewhere?

" Why do people even work there, if they don't give a hoot about your flag product?" Generally money. Nothing wrong with that.  I think a 'more important' thing to look at (and I've brought this up before), is why more people who give a hoot aren't trying to, or able to work in the company, and why you can't get your own employees actually excited about the product.

That being said, it makes perfect sense to hold events like this for new employees. Given the big layoffs at SO one year ago, I'm not sure if they are actually hiring though...

@Lundin marketing isn’t marketing the public platform.

@KevinB It's not like there's any big difference. Plus if you don't market the public platform, you won't get any new potential customers for Teams etc either. SO the company has never realized that the users of the public platform are either existing customers or potential customers. By not treating users as existing/potential customers but rather as some annoying by-product they have to suffer while running the site, they are losing major business. This has been a culture problem in the company for as long as I can remember, long before Teams and the current CEO.

Plainly: the ones most likely to buy ad space, job adverts or whatever are those already using the site. Not some unrelated mysterious people "out there" whom sales & marketing should hunt down separately.

One RL anecdote from long time ago. I were recruiting devs through an external recruiting company and they offered an advertising packet where the old SO jobs was included. Since I was already familiar with it as a long term user and knew how poorly it worked (non-existent candidate matching etc), I explained this to the recruiting company who didn't have much of a clue what SO was about. Then they stopped using SO jobs as well. Now had the feature worked fine then SO wouldn't even need to market it to me since I already knew of it as a user.

In terms of dogfooding, Stack does heavily utilize SO for Teams for lots of different purposes internally. When it comes to the public sites, most developers who work for Stack have a long history of using SO and some of the other tech sites, as many programmers around the world do. Some of our staff also came directly out of the community, being hired for their positions after being long time users or mods on a site. Community-a-thon is an opportunity for those employees to re-see the sight through the lens of a current community member.

And for many other employees in departments, such as sales, marketing/advertising, legal, accounting, administrative operations, etc, they may not have had much experience with the SE network before they got the job, so Community-a-thon is a great opportunity for them to gain deeper insight into the communities that make it up and what its like to be part of them.

@Sasha I'm also not questioning that such familiarization happens... but you're making it a huge deal here. I mean, that's something that would happen upon a new employee joining. To me that seems given, no need to make a PR about it. The long-term effects of the previous iterations were far from staggering, and some of the reports... quite stunning since they showed the level of ignorance across the employee base.

I think I've asked this before, in connection with other Community-a-Thons, but I'm going to ask it again.
Why do you need special events to encourage employees to participate on the sites and to become familiar with the people and communities that they help support?
Every employee should be given time during their workday to participate on network sites.
To encourage this, if one or more network sites that map to a job function or role within the company exist, then the company should map those sites to the roles and communicate that to employees. However, if no sites are related to their role at the company or the employee chooses to do so, they can participate on any site in the network.
Most people should be able to find at least one site to participate on, either related to their role at the company or some outside interest. And, like their participation in the Community-a-Thon, it doesn't need to be done using an account that indicates they are staff.
Participation should be defined as any user activity: asking questions, answering questions, leaving comments, voting, editing, working through the review queues. The minimum expected bar for participation should be low, but non-zero, so people get an understanding but do not generate low quality content. Generating content to meet evaluation criteria would not serve anyone's interest here.
Converting staff to contributors and curators in good standing by encouraging a steady level of effort would be far more beneficial to the communities than a week-long event once a year or so.

I imagine that SE DOES invite their employees to get involved in a more regular fashion, but I also know from personal experience that these "extracurriculars" usually get eaten up by other priorities. "Yeah I couldn't get on to Super User today, I needed to finish payroll and then do the reports for Prashanth and also budgeting for the Christmas party. Maybe tomorrow I'll have more time". Having a dedicated, scheduled event for doing activities actually helps kickstart participation, or at least offers SOME level of exposure which might otherwise never happen.

@Robotnik Why would this be an "extracurricular"? If that's the case, the problem is in another castle, and once-per-year PR stunts like what this appears to be won't change anything.

@DanMašek because it's still not their job to join a community. Doesn't matter whether they're programmers or finance or lawyers or whatever else - being asked by the company to "join in" IS an extracurricular, same as if they said "you have 1 day a year to do charity work". Or "join us at 3pm for our company Yoga session". Unless they are literally being paid to interact with the community (as in, a CM!) it's an extracurricular.

@Robotnik If "it's still not their job" is the general attitude, then no wonder it's going down the drain. Guess I'm weird, that's just not how I could operate, perhaps a personality defect.

@DanMašek Let's change tack here: if it were any other company, do you think a mandate that employees must evangelise the company and constantly use the product would be a healthy relationship? Where non-attendance on company events reflected negatively on their supposed loyalty to them and the system? Why should SE employees be any different? If I work for let's say Coca Cola, does it really matter if I don't drink Coke if my work is otherwise good?

@Robotnik Have you ever heard of "eating your own dog food"? Joel Spolsky, one of the original founders and creators of Stack Overflow, wrote a popular piece on the subject. It may be harder to justify for some roles than others, but having your people use and interact with the products and services that your companies offers and sells is incredibly beneficial.

@Robotnik I do agree that there are risks. However, putting use our products and services on everyone's performance evaluation would likely have a net positive. Even if it's 30 minutes in the review queues or one question (and follow-on engagement via comments, voting, etc.) or one or two answers a month or a quarter, that would be a significant increase in consistent engagement.

@Thomas I think the benefits of dogfooding are overstated. If you need your entire company to dogfood your product for QA purposes then your quality control probably sucks. And hell no- do not make it mandatory. Compulsory time is just going to lead to people doing the bare minumum, or worse: just clicking buttons until they don't have to any more. "Oh I need to do 10 reviews today? Shit, alright. Approve Approve, Approve, Approve, Reject, Reject, Reject, Approve, Reject, Approve. Great now I can go home." I do not want people forced to interact that do not want to be here.

@Robotnik "a mandate that employees must evangelise the company" A mandate? Why would you need to mandate that, that makes no sense. It's you who is suggesting that here. Why is it so odd that employees of company such as this should be enthusiastic about the product they make?

@DanMašek I don't think "enthusiastic" is the right word. I'd settle for "familiar", with all aspects of the product. By "product", I mean not only the platform, but the humans behind it that provide the content that is then sold (see the "knowledge-as-a-service" blog post).

@Robotnik Dogfooding doesn't always have to do with quality. It can help find problems missed in other forms of testing, but just being familiar with how end users experience the product goes a long way to making informed technical decisions. The effects of compulsory time depend on what that time is. 10 posts a week or 4 hours in review queues? That's probably excessive. 1 or 2 posts and associated engagement (voting on others, responding to comments) or 15-30 minutes in review queues every quarter? That's shouldn't be a problem.
